# How to implement a safe Facebook login/register/connect web service for a mobile application?

Tags: facebook, api, rest, authentication, language-agnostic

I have a web REST API for a mobile application which supports classic signup/signin with user/password and token authentication.

Since the signup is without email confirmation how could I implement a safe signup/signin/connect with facebook service?

My first approach: I get from mobile application `facebook_id`, `facebook_email`, `facebook_name`:

- search user by facebook, if exists perfect return that user, else create a new user with these params
- issue: I assume that a `facebook_id` can be easily found out by any other application.. so nothing is stopping me for assuming I'm someone else and login with his facebook_id
- possible solution: Get the `access_token` also from the mobile application and check on server side that the `access_token` is the correct one in relation with the `facebook_email` received

Another issue could be:

- Person A is creating an classic account with `personB@fake.com` email
- Person B, a week later, connects it's facebook account (with the same `personB@fake.com` email). The first idea would be to link the clasic account with this facebook account. But then the Person B would take over Person A's account.

**Optional:** Also what would is the best practice for token expiration on mobile applications. I've read something about 2 hours, but still `facebook` application is still logged after half of year I think.

For assuring the security, let's assume I can get anything important (access_token, email, ...) from client side in my webservice: what is the best practice that could ensure best security in this case: even `client-side` rules: should there be 2 distinct services for Login and SignUp? Anyway, a quick guildeline/step-by-step flow would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [Facebook Developer Login documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/)? They cover [login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/#loginflows) and [generating user & app tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#generating) (by calling the FB SDK for JavaScript ([`FB.GetAuthResponse`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getAuthResponse/)), in which case the [AuthResponse includes a userID parameter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/#checklogin) that you can map your app's id to). Token expiration is also handled by the FB SDK. Android login flow looks fairly straightforward, and iOS login flow looks even simpler.

Comment: It's not about how to use facebook API.. it's how to architect my web services to treat all the use-cases (mostly those listed in the question)